# How to insert ahead an element to an embedded array?

Tags: arrays, insert, rethinkdb

How to insert blow document

```
  {
      "author": "Vic Zhao",
      "text":  "hell..............."
  }
```

into blow document as first element of embedded array comments

```
{
   name: 'Me',
   comments: [{
      "author": "Joe S.",
      "text": "I'm Thirsty"
   },
  {
      "author": "Adder K.",
      "text":  "old content"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the prepend operation http://www.rethinkdb.com/api/#js:document_manipulation-prepend

```
r.table(...).get(...).update({
    comments: r.row('comments').prepend(newEntry)
  }).run(conn, callback)
```

Where newEntry must be replaced by the data you want to insert.